# How to correctly navigate to same and different page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Below is my code for a simple form in the create_session.php page. I am using the forma action method to navigate the user to the "QandATable.php" page when the user submits the form. But what I want is that if the user types in the number 1 in the number of sessions textbox, then navigate to the QandATable.php page wheh the user submits the form, else if it is any other number, then when the user submits the form, I want it to go back to the "create_session.php" (Back to its own page). Imagine it like you click on the submit button and it refreshes the page so it goes back to being a blank form, thats what I want to do if the number of sessions textbox contains a number which is bigger than '1'. How can this be done? I am using php and jquery code as well as basic html.

Thank You

```
 <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
      <p><strong>Number of Sessions you Require:</strong> <input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" /></p>
        <p><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;"/></p>      <!-- Prepare Questions here-->

    </form>
```

Comment: You could easily do it with jquery, but is there a reason you just dont check it on QandATable.php, and redirect directly from there?

Comment: Hi, There is a reason, lets say for example you fill in a form for 2 people, you fill in a form for one person and then when you submit the form, then the next thing you do is fill in the form for the second person. If its one person then when you submit form then you have finsihed, if there are multiple people then you fill in a form one at a time, fill a form submit then fill in a form for next person, then third person etc. Thats why I want to know how you could do this example where if textbox is '1' then navigate to the QandATable.php page else if more than 1, go back to same page

Comment: Yea but it seems easier to just make it submit to itself (create_session.php) and then submit form, redirect in php depending on the number. Because else it would be a mess keeping track on the number of session created. But im a little confused because if you have the "Number of sessions" on the create page, where do you create the person?

Comment: Hi, that create person is just an example to show what I am kind of looking for. All I want to know is if number of session is more than 1, how do you submit the form to itself, if it is 1 then submit to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of the `QandATable.php` script add:

```
if ($_POST['sessionNum']!=1) {
  header("Location: create_session.php");
  exit();
}
```

But as others have mentioned in the comments, you might as well just make the form submit to the `create_session.php` page and if it's successful then redirect to the next page.

Comment: Do not forget about `exit` after `header('Location: ...')`